# Any references to replacing the XmlSerialiaztioNBehavior for WCF?

Tags: wcf, xmlserializer

I need to hook up my own XmlSerializer (need to do some custom prepataions). They are all "valid" and easy to do when creating an XmlSerializer, but...
...when using WCF using the behavior am not creating the serializer. So I run into a problem.

Anyone has a reference how to replace the XmlSerialiaztionBehavior of WCF and to "inject" a custom prepared XmlSerializer?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [custom message formatters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx), or here on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733844.aspx).